# Finding row variance in R

Tags: r, matrix, variance

I've got a matrix in R version 3.6.3 and need to find the variance of each row. The function rowVars needs the METAMA package to work I believe that needs the limma package that isn't available for my version of R so I was wondering if anyone knows a way to get around this.

Comment: `matrixStats` also has a `rowVars` function for that.

Answer (score 0):

give an example of your data. if the data is in the matrix, then use `apply`

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(20), nrow = 4)
apply(x, 1, var)
```